# Why won't Kafka connect to Zookeeper?

Tags: linux, apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper, raspbian

I'm using a rasbery pi with Rasbian. I want to use Kafka to stream data from a camera to my phone. I downloaded this package from the Kafka website that contains Zookeeper and Kafka:

> https://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.cgi?path=/kafka/2.4.1/kafka_2.12-2.4.1.tgz

First I started zookeeper with the zookeeper-server-start.sh located in the bin directory with:
"sudo bin/zookeeper-server-start.sh config/zookeeper.properties" in the terminal. I got back:

```
    [2020-04-07 17:56:44,843] INFO Reading configuration from: config/zookeeper.properties (org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerConfig)
[2020-04-07 17:56:44,854] WARN config/zookeeper.properties is relative. Prepend ./ to indicate that you're sure! (org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerConfig)
[2020-04-07 17:56:44,936] INFO clientPortAddress is 0.0.0.0:2181 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerConfig)
[2020-04-07 17:56:44,937] INFO secureClientPort is not set (org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerConfig)
[2020-04-07 17:56:44,975] INFO autopurge.snapRetainCount set to 3 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.DatadirCleanupManager)
[2020-04-07 17:56:44,976] INFO autopurge.purgeInterval set to 0 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.DatadirCleanupManager)
[2020-04-07 17:56:44,978] INFO Purge task is not scheduled. (org.apache.zookeeper.server.DatadirCleanupManager)
[2020-04-07 17:56:44,979] WARN Either no config or no quorum defined in config, running  in standalone mode (org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerMain)
[2020-04-07 17:56:45,010] INFO Log4j found with jmx enabled. (org.apache.zookeeper.jmx.ManagedUtil)
[2020-04-07 17:56:45,263] INFO Reading configuration from: config/zookeeper.properties (org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerConfig)
[2020-04-07 17:56:45,264] WARN config/zookeeper.properties is relative. Prepend ./ to indicate that you're sure! (org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerConfig)
[2020-04-07 17:56:45,268] INFO clientPortAddress is 0.0.0.0:2181 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerConfig)
[2020-04-07 17:56:45,269] INFO secureClientPort is not set (org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerConfig)
[2020-04-07 17:56:45,271] INFO Starting server (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServerMain)
[2020-04-07 17:56:45,319] INFO zookeeper.snapshot.trust.empty : false (org.apache.zookeeper.server.persistence.FileTxnSnapLog)
[2020-04-07 17:56:45,483] INFO Server environment:zookeeper.version=3.5.7-f0fdd52973d373ffd9c86b81d99842dc2c7f660e, built on 02/10/2020 11:30 GMT (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer)
[2020-04-07 17:56:45,484] INFO Server environment:host.name=Rupert (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer)
[2020-04-07 17:56:45,485] INFO Server environment:java.version=11.0.6 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer)
[2020-04-07 17:56:45,486] INFO Server environment:java.vendor=Raspbian (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer)
[2020-04-07 17:56:45,487] INFO Server environment:java.home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-armhf (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer)
[2020-04-07 17:56:45,488] INFO Server environment:java.class.path=/usr/local/kafka/bin/../libs/activation-1.1.1.jar:/usr/local/kafka/bin/../libs/aopalliance-repackaged-2.5.0.jar:/usr/local/kafka/bin/../libs/argparse4j-0.7.0.jar:/usr/local/kafka/bin/../libs/audience-annotations-0.5.0.jar:/usr/local/kafka/bin/../libs/commons-cli-1.4.jar:/usr/local/kafka/bin/../libs/commons-lang3-3.8.1.jar:/usr/local/kafka/bin/../libs/connect-api-2.4.1.jar:/usr/local/kafka/bin/../libs/connect-basic-auth-extension-2.4.1.jar:/usr/local/kafka/bin/../libs/connect-file-2.4.1.jar:/usr/local/kafka/bin/../libs/connect-json-2.4.1.jar:/usr/local/kafka/bin/../libs/connect-mirror-2.4.1.jar:/usr/local/kafka/bin/../libs/connect-mirror-client-2.4.1.jar:/usr/local/kafka/bin/../libs/connect-runtime-2.4.1.jar:/usr/local/kafka/bin/../libs/connect-transforms-2.4.1.jar:/usr/local/kafka/bin/../libs/guava-20.0.jar:/usr/local/kafka/bin/../libs/hk2-api-2.5.0.jar:/usr/local/kafka/bin/../libs/hk2-locator-2.5.0.jar:/usr/local/kafka/bin/../libs/hk2-utils-2.5.0.jar:/usr/local/kafka/bin/../libs/jackson-annotations-2.10.0.jar:/usr/local/kafka/bin/../libs/jackson-core-2.10.0.jar:/usr/local/kafka/bin/../libs/jackson-databind-2.10.0.jar:/usr/local/kafka/bin/../libs/jackson-dataformat-csv-2.10.0.jar:/usr/local/kafka/bin/../libs/jackson-datatype-jdk8-2.10.0.jar:/usr/local/kafka/bin/../libs/jackson-jaxrs-base-2.10.0.jar:/usr/local/kafka/bin/../libs/jackson-jaxrs-json-provider-2.10.0.jar:/usr/local/kafka/bin/../libs/jackson-module-jaxb-annotations-2.10.0.jar:/usr/local/kafka/bin/../libs/jackson-module-paranamer-2.10.0.jar:/usr/local/kafka/bin/../libs/jackson-module-scala_2.12-2.10.0.jar:/usr/local/kafka/bin/../libs/jakarta.activation-api-1.2.1.jar:/usr/local/kafka/bin/../libs/jakarta.annotation-api-1.3.4.jar:/usr/local/kafka/bin/../libs/jakarta.inject-2.5.0.jar:/usr/local/kafka/bin/../libs/jakarta.ws.rs-api-2.1.5.jar:/usr/local/kafka/bin/../libs/jakarta.xml.bind-api-2.3.2.jar:/usr/local/kafka/bin/../libs/javassist-3.22.0-CR2.jar:/usr/local/kafka/bin/../libs/javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar:/usr/local/kafka/bin/../libs/javax.ws.rs-api-2.1.1.jar:/usr/local/kafka/bin/../libs/jaxb-api-2.3.0.jar:/usr/local/kafka/bin/../libs/jersey-client-2.28.jar:/usr/local/kafka/bin/../libs/jersey-common-2.28.jar:/usr/local/kafka/bin/../libs/jersey-container-servlet-2.28.jar:/usr/local/kafka/bin/../libs/jersey-container-servlet-core-2.28.jar:/usr/local/kafka/bin/../libs/jersey-hk2-2.28.jar:/usr/local/kafka/bin/../libs/jersey-media-jaxb-2.28.jar:/usr/local/kafka/bin/../libs/jersey-server-2.28.jar:/usr/local/kafka/bin/../libs/jetty-client-9.4.20.v20190813.jar:/usr/local/kafka/bin/../libs/jetty-continuation-9.4.20.v20190813.jar:/usr/local/kafka/bin/../libs/jetty-http-9.4.20.v20190813.jar:/usr/local/kafka/bin/../libs/jetty-io-9.4.20.v20190813.jar:/usr/local/kafka/bin/../libs/jetty-security-9.4.20.v20190813.jar:/usr/local/kafka/bin/../libs/jetty-server-9.4.20.v20190813.jar:/usr/local/kafka/bin/../libs/jetty-servlet-9.4.20.v20190813.jar:/usr/local/kafka/bin/../libs/jetty-servlets-9.4.20.v20190813.jar:/usr/local/kafka/bin/../libs/jetty-util-9.4.20.v20190813.jar:/usr/local/kafka/bin/../libs/jopt-simple-5.0.4.jar:/usr/local/kafka/bin/../libs/kafka_2.12-2.4.1.jar:/usr/local/kafka/bin/../libs/kafka_2.12-2.4.1-sources.jar:/usr/local/kafka/bin/../libs/kafka-clients-2.4.1.jar:/usr/local/kafka/bin/../libs/kafka-log4j-appender-2.4.1.jar:/usr/local/kafka/bin/../libs/kafka-streams-2.4.1.jar:/usr/local/kafka/bin/../libs/kafka-streams-examples-2.4.1.jar:/usr/local/kafka/bin/../libs/kafka-streams-scala_2.12-2.4.1.jar:/usr/local/kafka/bin/../libs/kafka-streams-test-utils-2.4.1.jar:/usr/local/kafka/bin/../libs/kafka-tools-2.4.1.jar:/usr/local/kafka/bin/../libs/log4j-1.2.17.jar:/usr/local/kafka/bin/../libs/lz4-java-1.6.0.jar:/usr/local/kafka/bin/../libs/maven-artifact-3.6.1.jar:/usr/local/kafka/bin/../libs/metrics-core-2.2.0.jar:/usr/local/kafka/bin/../libs/netty-buffer-4.1.45.Final.jar:/usr/local/kafka/bin/../libs/netty-codec-4.1.45.Final.jar:/usr/local/kafka/bin/../libs/netty-common-4.1.45.Final.jar:/usr/local/kafka/bin/../libs/netty-handler-4.1.45.Final.jar:/usr/local/kafka/bin/../libs/netty-resolver-4.1.45.Final.jar:/usr/local/kafka/bin/../libs/netty-transport-4.1.45.Final.jar:/usr/local/kafka/bin/../libs/netty-transport-native-epoll-4.1.45.Final.jar:/usr/local/kafka/bin/../libs/netty-transport-native-unix-common-4.1.45.Final.jar:/usr/local/kafka/bin/../libs/osgi-resource-locator-1.0.1.jar:/usr/local/kafka/bin/../libs/paranamer-2.8.jar:/usr/local/kafka/bin/../libs/plexus-utils-3.2.0.jar:/usr/local/kafka/bin/../libs/reflections-0.9.11.jar:/usr/local/kafka/bin/../libs/rocksdbjni-5.18.3.jar:/usr/local/kafka/bin/../libs/scala-collection-compat_2.12-2.1.2.jar:/usr/local/kafka/bin/../libs/scala-java8-compat_2.12-0.9.0.jar:/usr/local/kafka/bin/../libs/scala-library-2.12.10.jar:/usr/local/kafka/bin/../libs/scala-logging_2.12-3.9.2.jar:/usr/local/kafka/bin/../libs/scala-reflect-2.12.10.jar:/usr/local/kafka/bin/../libs/slf4j-api-1.7.28.jar:/usr/local/kafka/bin/../libs/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.28.jar:/usr/local/kafka/bin/../libs/snappy-java-1.1.7.3.jar:/usr/local/kafka/bin/../libs/validation-api-2.0.1.Final.jar:/usr/local/kafka/bin/../libs/zookeeper-3.5.7.jar:/usr/local/kafka/bin/../libs/zookeeper-jute-3.5.7.jar:/usr/local/kafka/bin/../libs/zstd-jni-1.4.3-1.jar (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer)
[2020-04-07 17:56:45,498] INFO Server environment:java.library.path=/usr/java/packages/lib:/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/jni:/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf:/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf:/usr/lib/jni:/lib:/usr/lib (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer)
[2020-04-07 17:56:45,499] INFO Server environment:java.io.tmpdir=/tmp (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer)
[2020-04-07 17:56:45,500] INFO Server environment:java.compiler=<NA> (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer)
[2020-04-07 17:56:45,501] INFO Server environment:os.name=Linux (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer)
[2020-04-07 17:56:45,502] INFO Server environment:os.arch=arm (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer)
[2020-04-07 17:56:45,503] INFO Server environment:os.version=4.19.66-v7+ (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer)
[2020-04-07 17:56:45,504] INFO Server environment:user.name=root (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer)
[2020-04-07 17:56:45,506] INFO Server environment:user.home=/root (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer)
[2020-04-07 17:56:45,507] INFO Server environment:user.dir=/usr/local/kafka (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer)
[2020-04-07 17:56:45,508] INFO Server environment:os.memory.free=493MB (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer)
[2020-04-07 17:56:45,509] INFO Server environment:os.memory.max=512MB (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer)
[2020-04-07 17:56:45,510] INFO Server environment:os.memory.total=512MB (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer)
[2020-04-07 17:56:45,529] INFO minSessionTimeout set to 6000 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer)
[2020-04-07 17:56:45,531] INFO maxSessionTimeout set to 60000 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer)
[2020-04-07 17:56:45,539] INFO Created server with tickTime 3000 minSessionTimeout 6000 maxSessionTimeout 60000 datadir /tmp/zookeeper/version-2 snapdir /tmp/zookeeper/version-2 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer)
[2020-04-07 17:56:45,661] INFO Using org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxnFactory as server connection factory (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ServerCnxnFactory)
[2020-04-07 17:56:45,699] INFO Configuring NIO connection handler with 10s sessionless connection timeout, 1 selector thread(s), 8 worker threads, and 64 kB direct buffers. (org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxnFactory)
[2020-04-07 17:56:45,773] INFO binding to port 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxnFactory)
[2020-04-07 17:56:45,965] INFO zookeeper.snapshotSizeFactor = 0.33 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZKDatabase)
[2020-04-07 17:56:45,994] INFO Reading snapshot /tmp/zookeeper/version-2/snapshot.0 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.persistence.FileSnap)
[2020-04-07 17:56:46,076] INFO Snapshotting: 0x0 to /tmp/zookeeper/version-2/snapshot.0 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.persistence.FileTxnSnapLog)
[2020-04-07 17:56:46,377] INFO Using checkIntervalMs=60000 maxPerMinute=10000 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ContainerManager)
```

I believe that his is correct, but please do bring anything to my attention.

Next I tried to run Kafka using "sudo bin/kafka-server-start.sh config/server.properties" and after running for 10 seconds it returned:

```
[2020-04-07 17:49:40,577] INFO Registered kafka:type=kafka.Log4jController MBean (kafka.utils.Log4jControllerRegistration$)
[2020-04-07 17:49:47,215] INFO Registered signal handlers for TERM, INT, HUP (org.apache.kafka.common.utils.LoggingSignalHandler)
[2020-04-07 17:49:47,222] INFO starting (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
[2020-04-07 17:49:47,233] INFO Connecting to zookeeper on localhost:2181 (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
[2020-04-07 17:49:47,558] INFO [ZooKeeperClient Kafka server] Initializing a new session to localhost:2181. (kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClient)
[2020-04-07 17:49:47,679] INFO Client environment:zookeeper.version=3.5.7-f0fdd52973d373ffd9c86b81d99842dc2c7f660e, built on 02/10/2020 11:30 GMT (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2020-04-07 17:49:47,681] INFO Client environment:host.name=Rupert (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2020-04-07 17:49:47,682] INFO Client environment:java.version=11.0.6 (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2020-04-07 17:49:47,682] INFO Client environment:java.vendor=Raspbian (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2020-04-07 17:49:47,683] INFO Client environment:java.home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-armhf (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2020-04-07 17:49:47,684] INFO Client environment:java.class.path=/usr/local/kafka/bin/../libs/activation-1.1.1.jar:/usr/local/kafka/bin/../libs/aopalliance-repackaged-2.5.0.jar:/usr/local/kafka/bin/../libs/argparse4j-0.7.0.jar:/usr/local/kafka/bin/../libs/audience-annotations-0.5.0.jar:/usr/local/kafka/bin/../libs/commons-cli-1.4.jar:/usr/local/kafka/bin/../libs/commons-lang3-3.8.1.jar:/usr/local/kafka/bin/../libs/connect-api-2.4.1.jar:/usr/local/kafka/bin/../libs/connect-basic-auth-extension-2.4.1.jar:/usr/local/kafka/bin/../libs/connect-file-2.4.1.jar:/usr/local/kafka/bin/../libs/connect-json-2.4.1.jar:/usr/local/kafka/bin/../libs/connect-mirror-2.4.1.jar:/usr/local/kafka/bin/../libs/connect-mirror-client-2.4.1.jar:/usr/local/kafka/bin/../libs/connect-runtime-2.4.1.jar:/usr/local/kafka/bin/../libs/connect-transforms-2.4.1.jar:/usr/local/kafka/bin/../libs/guava-20.0.jar:/usr/local/kafka/bin/../libs/hk2-api-2.5.0.jar:/usr/local/kafka/bin/../libs/hk2-locator-2.5.0.jar:/usr/local/kafka/bin/../libs/hk2-utils-2.5.0.jar:/usr/local/kafka/bin/../libs/jackson-annotations-2.10.0.jar:/usr/local/kafka/bin/../libs/jackson-core-2.10.0.jar:/usr/local/kafka/bin/../libs/jackson-databind-2.10.0.jar:/usr/local/kafka/bin/../libs/jackson-dataformat-csv-2.10.0.jar:/usr/local/kafka/bin/../libs/jackson-datatype-jdk8-2.10.0.jar:/usr/local/kafka/bin/../libs/jackson-jaxrs-base-2.10.0.jar:/usr/local/kafka/bin/../libs/jackson-jaxrs-json-provider-2.10.0.jar:/usr/local/kafka/bin/../libs/jackson-module-jaxb-annotations-2.10.0.jar:/usr/local/kafka/bin/../libs/jackson-module-paranamer-2.10.0.jar:/usr/local/kafka/bin/../libs/jackson-module-scala_2.12-2.10.0.jar:/usr/local/kafka/bin/../libs/jakarta.activation-api-1.2.1.jar:/usr/local/kafka/bin/../libs/jakarta.annotation-api-1.3.4.jar:/usr/local/kafka/bin/../libs/jakarta.inject-2.5.0.jar:/usr/local/kafka/bin/../libs/jakarta.ws.rs-api-2.1.5.jar:/usr/local/kafka/bin/../libs/jakarta.xml.bind-api-2.3.2.jar:/usr/local/kafka/bin/../libs/javassist-3.22.0-CR2.jar:/usr/local/kafka/bin/../libs/javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar:/usr/local/kafka/bin/../libs/javax.ws.rs-api-2.1.1.jar:/usr/local/kafka/bin/../libs/jaxb-api-2.3.0.jar:/usr/local/kafka/bin/../libs/jersey-client-2.28.jar:/usr/local/kafka/bin/../libs/jersey-common-2.28.jar:/usr/local/kafka/bin/../libs/jersey-container-servlet-2.28.jar:/usr/local/kafka/bin/../libs/jersey-container-servlet-core-2.28.jar:/usr/local/kafka/bin/../libs/jersey-hk2-2.28.jar:/usr/local/kafka/bin/../libs/jersey-media-jaxb-2.28.jar:/usr/local/kafka/bin/../libs/jersey-server-2.28.jar:/usr/local/kafka/bin/../libs/jetty-client-9.4.20.v20190813.jar:/usr/local/kafka/bin/../libs/jetty-continuation-9.4.20.v20190813.jar:/usr/local/kafka/bin/../libs/jetty-http-9.4.20.v20190813.jar:/usr/local/kafka/bin/../libs/jetty-io-9.4.20.v20190813.jar:/usr/local/kafka/bin/../libs/jetty-security-9.4.20.v20190813.jar:/usr/local/kafka/bin/../libs/jetty-server-9.4.20.v20190813.jar:/usr/local/kafka/bin/../libs/jetty-servlet-9.4.20.v20190813.jar:/usr/local/kafka/bin/../libs/jetty-servlets-9.4.20.v20190813.jar:/usr/local/kafka/bin/../libs/jetty-util-9.4.20.v20190813.jar:/usr/local/kafka/bin/../libs/jopt-simple-5.0.4.jar:/usr/local/kafka/bin/../libs/kafka_2.12-2.4.1.jar:/usr/local/kafka/bin/../libs/kafka_2.12-2.4.1-sources.jar:/usr/local/kafka/bin/../libs/kafka-clients-2.4.1.jar:/usr/local/kafka/bin/../libs/kafka-log4j-appender-2.4.1.jar:/usr/local/kafka/bin/../libs/kafka-streams-2.4.1.jar:/usr/local/kafka/bin/../libs/kafka-streams-examples-2.4.1.jar:/usr/local/kafka/bin/../libs/kafka-streams-scala_2.12-2.4.1.jar:/usr/local/kafka/bin/../libs/kafka-streams-test-utils-2.4.1.jar:/usr/local/kafka/bin/../libs/kafka-tools-2.4.1.jar:/usr/local/kafka/bin/../libs/log4j-1.2.17.jar:/usr/local/kafka/bin/../libs/lz4-java-1.6.0.jar:/usr/local/kafka/bin/../libs/maven-artifact-3.6.1.jar:/usr/local/kafka/bin/../libs/metrics-core-2.2.0.jar:/usr/local/kafka/bin/../libs/netty-buffer-4.1.45.Final.jar:/usr/local/kafka/bin/../libs/netty-codec-4.1.45.Final.jar:/usr/local/kafka/bin/../libs/netty-common-4.1.45.Final.jar:/usr/local/kafka/bin/../libs/netty-handler-4.1.45.Final.jar:/usr/local/kafka/bin/../libs/netty-resolver-4.1.45.Final.jar:/usr/local/kafka/bin/../libs/netty-transport-4.1.45.Final.jar:/usr/local/kafka/bin/../libs/netty-transport-native-epoll-4.1.45.Final.jar:/usr/local/kafka/bin/../libs/netty-transport-native-unix-common-4.1.45.Final.jar:/usr/local/kafka/bin/../libs/osgi-resource-locator-1.0.1.jar:/usr/local/kafka/bin/../libs/paranamer-2.8.jar:/usr/local/kafka/bin/../libs/plexus-utils-3.2.0.jar:/usr/local/kafka/bin/../libs/reflections-0.9.11.jar:/usr/local/kafka/bin/../libs/rocksdbjni-5.18.3.jar:/usr/local/kafka/bin/../libs/scala-collection-compat_2.12-2.1.2.jar:/usr/local/kafka/bin/../libs/scala-java8-compat_2.12-0.9.0.jar:/usr/local/kafka/bin/../libs/scala-library-2.12.10.jar:/usr/local/kafka/bin/../libs/scala-logging_2.12-3.9.2.jar:/usr/local/kafka/bin/../libs/scala-reflect-2.12.10.jar:/usr/local/kafka/bin/../libs/slf4j-api-1.7.28.jar:/usr/local/kafka/bin/../libs/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.28.jar:/usr/local/kafka/bin/../libs/snappy-java-1.1.7.3.jar:/usr/local/kafka/bin/../libs/validation-api-2.0.1.Final.jar:/usr/local/kafka/bin/../libs/zookeeper-3.5.7.jar:/usr/local/kafka/bin/../libs/zookeeper-jute-3.5.7.jar:/usr/local/kafka/bin/../libs/zstd-jni-1.4.3-1.jar (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2020-04-07 17:49:47,693] INFO Client environment:java.library.path=/usr/java/packages/lib:/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/jni:/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf:/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf:/usr/lib/jni:/lib:/usr/lib (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2020-04-07 17:49:47,695] INFO Client environment:java.io.tmpdir=/tmp (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2020-04-07 17:49:47,696] INFO Client environment:java.compiler=<NA> (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2020-04-07 17:49:47,697] INFO Client environment:os.name=Linux (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2020-04-07 17:49:47,698] INFO Client environment:os.arch=arm (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2020-04-07 17:49:47,699] INFO Client environment:os.version=4.19.66-v7+ (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2020-04-07 17:49:47,700] INFO Client environment:user.name=root (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2020-04-07 17:49:47,701] INFO Client environment:user.home=/root (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2020-04-07 17:49:47,702] INFO Client environment:user.dir=/usr/local/kafka (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2020-04-07 17:49:47,703] INFO Client environment:os.memory.free=975MB (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2020-04-07 17:49:47,704] INFO Client environment:os.memory.max=1024MB (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2020-04-07 17:49:47,704] INFO Client environment:os.memory.total=1024MB (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2020-04-07 17:49:47,769] INFO Initiating client connection, connectString=localhost:2181 sessionTimeout=6000 watcher=kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClient$ZooKeeperClientWatcher$@114918a (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2020-04-07 17:49:47,887] INFO Setting -D jdk.tls.rejectClientInitiatedRenegotiation=true to disable client-initiated TLS renegotiation (org.apache.zookeeper.common.X509Util)
[2020-04-07 17:49:48,017] INFO jute.maxbuffer value is 4194304 Bytes (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocket)
[2020-04-07 17:49:48,130] INFO zookeeper.request.timeout value is 0. feature enabled= (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
[2020-04-07 17:49:48,313] INFO [ZooKeeperClient Kafka server] Waiting until connected. (kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClient)
[2020-04-07 17:49:48,449] INFO Opening socket connection to server localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error) (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
[2020-04-07 17:49:48,557] INFO Socket error occurred: localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:2181: Connection refused (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
[2020-04-07 17:49:49,678] INFO Opening socket connection to server localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error) (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
[2020-04-07 17:49:49,682] INFO Socket error occurred: localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:2181: Connection refused (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
[2020-04-07 17:49:50,784] INFO Opening socket connection to server localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error) (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
[2020-04-07 17:49:50,787] INFO Socket error occurred: localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:2181: Connection refused (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
[2020-04-07 17:49:51,890] INFO Opening socket connection to server localhost/127.0.0.1:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error) (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
[2020-04-07 17:49:51,894] INFO Socket error occurred: localhost/127.0.0.1:2181: Connection refused (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
[2020-04-07 17:49:52,997] INFO Opening socket connection to server localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error) (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
[2020-04-07 17:49:53,000] INFO Socket error occurred: localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:2181: Connection refused (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
[2020-04-07 17:49:54,114] INFO Opening socket connection to server localhost/127.0.0.1:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error) (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
[2020-04-07 17:49:54,118] INFO Socket error occurred: localhost/127.0.0.1:2181: Connection refused (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
[2020-04-07 17:49:54,353] INFO [ZooKeeperClient Kafka server] Closing. (kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClient)
[2020-04-07 17:49:55,221] INFO Opening socket connection to server localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error) (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
[2020-04-07 17:49:55,375] INFO Session: 0x0 closed (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2020-04-07 17:49:55,396] INFO EventThread shut down for session: 0x0 (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
[2020-04-07 17:49:55,412] INFO [ZooKeeperClient Kafka server] Closed. (kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClient)
[2020-04-07 17:49:55,449] ERROR Fatal error during KafkaServer startup. Prepare to shutdown (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClientTimeoutException: Timed out waiting for connection while in state: CONNECTING
    at kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClient.$anonfun$waitUntilConnected$3(ZooKeeperClient.scala:259)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
    at kafka.utils.CoreUtils$.inLock(CoreUtils.scala:253)
    at kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClient.waitUntilConnected(ZooKeeperClient.scala:255)
    at kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClient.<init>(ZooKeeperClient.scala:113)
    at kafka.zk.KafkaZkClient$.apply(KafkaZkClient.scala:1858)
    at kafka.server.KafkaServer.createZkClient$1(KafkaServer.scala:375)
    at kafka.server.KafkaServer.initZkClient(KafkaServer.scala:399)
    at kafka.server.KafkaServer.startup(KafkaServer.scala:207)
    at kafka.server.KafkaServerStartable.startup(KafkaServerStartable.scala:44)
    at kafka.Kafka$.main(Kafka.scala:84)
    at kafka.Kafka.main(Kafka.scala)
[2020-04-07 17:49:55,480] INFO shutting down (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
[2020-04-07 17:49:55,577] INFO shut down completed (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
[2020-04-07 17:49:55,583] ERROR Exiting Kafka. (kafka.server.KafkaServerStartable)
[2020-04-07 17:49:55,612] INFO shutting down (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
```

My assumption is that Kafka can't reach zookeeper but I really have no clue.

Is there a way I can test if zookeeper is working?
Thanks to anyone who helps, stay healthy.

Answer (score 0):

When I pressed ctrl+shift+c to get rid of the text that showed up afterwards it also undid what needed to happen.